# MySQL Update entire table in one query

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, insert-update

I'm trying to load and update the content of a entire table. I have no problem loading the data but it won't update.. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here:

```
while($show_table   = mysql_fetch_array($result_table)){
    echo "<tr><td><input type='text' name='table_id' value='" . 
        $show_table["id"] . "'/><input type='text' name='table_date' value='" . $show_table["date"] . "'/>
        </td><td>&euro; <input type='text' name='table_week' value='" . $show_table["week"] . "'/>
        </td><td>&euro; <input type='text' name='table_midweek' value='" . $show_table["midweek"] . "'/>
        </td><td>&euro; <input type='text' name='table_weekend' value='" . $show_table["weekend"] . "'/>
        </td><td><input type='text' name='table_type' value='" . $show_table["type"] . "'/>
        </td><td><input type='text' name='table_information' value='" . $show_table["information"] . "'/></td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>
<p><input type='submit' id='form_submit' name='update_confirm' value='Tarieven bijwerken'></p>
</form>";

if ($_POST['update_confirm'] == 'Tarieven bijwerken') {
    $id = $_POST['table_id'];
    $date = $_POST['table_date'];
    $week = $_POST['table_week'];
    $midweek = $_POST['table_midweek'];
    $weekend = $_POST['table_weekend'];
    $type = $_POST['table_type'];
    $information = $_POST['table_information'];

    $update_table = "UPDATE tarieven SET date='$date', week='$week', midweek='$midweek', weekend='$weekend', type='$type', information='$information' WHERE id='$id';";
    $confirm_table  = mysql_query($update_table);

} else {
}
```

Comment: Did you try printing the query?Check what the query is after printing and try running it in the mysql admin SQL prompt.Any specific error would be highlighted there!Try and add **more details**!

Comment: are you receiving any error?, are you sure that update_confirm=='Tarieven bijwerken'? what is the table structure? you need to be more specific

Comment: You should read up on sql injection.

Comment: Not that it matters but you should escape the post data because of sql injections, mysql structure plz

Comment: Do you have specified method="post" in form open tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query updates only 1 row, as specified by `UPDATE tarieven SET ... WHERE id='$id'` - although you are looping through all the records and displaying them, the update is outside the loop.

Comment: You could specify in the form that id is `1' OR '1` :-)

Comment: Indeed - I was quoting the original text. Perhaps PHP/MySQL questions should get an auto-comment pointing towards sql-injection best practices...

Comment: Hi Raad, I think you are right! With the update in the loop it works the way I want! Thanks you all for the help. (I want to show you the results after fix but I have to wait for 8 hours..)